# this program used to avoid datarace

Tags: linux, ubuntu

how do I implement a solution to the following question?

```
public void safeDeposit(int valueToDeposit) throws Exception
```

This method takes an input, a value, and put (add/deposit) it to the wallet, i.e., update the database (the file). Again, you must implement necessary protections in this method to avoid data races.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for exam answers, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Read about **Synchronization** in JAVA. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html